# $k\left[x,y\right]$ is not integral over the $k\left[xy,y\right]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to prove that the polynomial ring $k\left[x,y\right]$
  is not integral over the subring $k\left[xy,y\right]$
 , where $k$
  is a field. My claim is that $x$
  is not integral over $k\left[xy,y\right]$
 , but I cannot proceed in the proof of claim. Any suggestions, helps or comments? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest thing is probably to show that (1) $k[xy,y] \simeq k[u,v]$ is already a polynomial ring, hence integrally closed in its fraction field (2) figure out what the fraction field of $k[xy,y]$ is (3) show that $x \notin k[xy,y]$.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $x$ satisfies a monic equation over $k[xy,y]$:
$$
x^n+a_{n-1}(xy,y)x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(xy,y)x+a_0(xy,y)=0
$$
where $a_j \in k[x,y]$.
Evaluating at $y=0$, we get:
$$
x^n+a_{n-1}(0,0)x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(0,0)x+a_0(0,0)=0
$$
where $a_j(0,0) \in k$. This implies that $a_j(0,0)=0$ for all $j$. But then
$x^n=0$, a contradiction.